# How to add json data to array or similar using Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, xcode, swift3

I am fairly new to Swift and I am having a few issues with getting understanding how to do what I want to do.

I am currently testing some stuff with json.
What I am trying to do is to append the data I get from my json data into an array. And when my array contains the data I wish to present it to my UICollectionView. I am assuming that I should be using an array.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func getData() {

        let path = "http://myurl/test.json"
        let url = URL(string: path)
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

            let json = JSON(data: data!)

            for result in json["dokumentstatus"]["dokutskott"]["utskott"].array! {

                let punkter = result["punkt"].string!
                print("punkt: \(punkt)")

                let rubrik = result["rubrik"].string
                print("rubrik: \(rubrik)")

                let forslag = result["forslag"].string
                print("förslag: \(forslag)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return //someArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

        cell.customLabel.text = //Put the data form rubrik variable
            cell.customTW.text = //Put the data from foreleg variable

        return cell

    }
}
```

the function `getData()` gets the correct json data I just need help understanding how to put this data to an array.
(Also, I know I probably shouldn't be getting the data in the ViewController, but this is only a test.)

```
import Foundation

class Information: NSObject {
    var punkter: String?
    var rubrik: String?
    var forslag: String?
}
```

I'm thinking that maybe I should be using an array that looks something like this:`var someArray = [Information]()`
But I do not know how to then use my `getData()`
Or maybe I should be using three different arrays, one for each of my json variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're still using a custom class (well done!, *three different arrays* are horrible) it's correct to declare a data source array like you suggested

```
var someArray = [Information]()
```

Most likely a struct is sufficient, I recommend to use non-optional strings

```
struct Information {
    var punkter : String
    var rubrik : String
    var forslag : String
}
```

If the properties won't change you could even use `let` to make the properties constants.

To populate the array use the nil coalescing operator to check for `nil`,create the `Information` instance with the memberwise initializer and append the instance to the datasource array. Then reload the collection view on the main thread.

```
...
for result in json["dokumentstatus"]["dokutskott"]["utskott"].array! {

  let punkter = result["punkt"].string ?? ""
  let rubrik = result["rubrik"].string ?? ""
  let forslag = result["forslag"].string ?? ""
  let information = Information(punkter:punkter, rubrik:rubrik, forslag:forslag)
  self.someArray.append(information)

}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
...
```

**Edit:**

To display the data in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` use

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    let information = someArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.customLabel.text = information.rubrik
    cell.customTW.text = information.foreleg
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I followed your answer and my CollectionView is now loading in the correct amount of cells to my View.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted comment before finishing writing everything. So to continue my question I am now wondering how do I get the label in my cell to get the value of "rubrik" and my TextView to get the value of "forslag".   I tried to simply do this: `cell.customLabel.text = someArray[indexPath.row]` (I could feel that it wouldnt work). So how can I get the value from `someArray` or the `struct`? and thank you very much for helping.

Comment: Thank you very for helping me. It works like intended now and I have learnt something new.